# How to Select a keyword from username or city in single query

Tags: php, mysql, json, database

How to select data from two columns in same table in a single query.
for example select name "waseem" from username if not found check in city row.

[image: Users Table]

Comment: What did you do to get the data for one column actually ? (sure you can find the solution using logic and some clues)

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from <table_name> where name like 'waseem' or city like 'waseem';
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with other's answers but with slight modification. If there is a record **waseem ahemed** and your only looking for **waseem** wont be searched in other answered query.

You need to use the wildcard **%** if you want to search for waseem.

I highly suggest you not to use * for selecting the column names because of the performance issues.

```
SELECT name, username, password WHERE name LIKE '%waseem%' OR city LIKE '%waseem%'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE row_name1 LIKE 'value' OR row_name2 LIKE 'value'
```